# What's the best practice for getting a value from a combobox on a userform?

Tags: vba

There's a lot of information and a lot that you can do with userforms but I can't really find a standard way to use them.  Let's say I have a userform with a standard dropdown list that asks someone to choose a fruit.  In the userform code I will put the below code after adding a combo box called `fruitcombo`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    userform1.fruitcombo.AddItem "Peach"
    userform1.fruitcombo.AddItem "Pear"
    userform1.fruitcombo.AddItem "Grape"
End Sub
```

I will also add a commandbutton which will be labeled `"Submit"` and in that event:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

That's where it starts to get hazy.  What's the best way to capture the answer that was selected?  One way I can think would be to make a global variable called fruitanswer and then instead of the `Me.Hide` we can skip straight to `Unload Me`

Ex:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    fruitanswer = fruitcombo.value
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Or we can have `fruitanswer` as a private variable in the module where the userform is called and then unload it in there.  There are also multiple ways to initialize the userform.  I'm also wondering the best way to initialize it.  The `Show` method will automatically initialize it, but the `Hide` method WON'T automatically de-initialize it.  For that, the `Unload` statement is necessary.  So does anyone initialize it before calling the `Show` method using the `Load` statement?

Ex:

```
Load userform1 'Any point to including this?
userform1.show
'user chooses a fruit and clicks submit button
'userform is hidden by commandbutton but not unloaded yet
fruitanswer = fruitcombo.value
Unload userform1
```

Out of these options, which is the best method?  Is there anything to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole thing in a single function call:

```
strFruit = UserForm1.GetFruit()
```

Then, in your `UserForm`, have it do the work of displaying and unloading itself like so:

```
Private bOK As Boolean

Public Function GetFruit() As String
    bOK = False
    Me.Show vbModal
    If bOK Then GetFruit = ComboBox1.Text
    Unload Me
End Function

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    bOK = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

This assumes you have buttons named `cmdOK` and `cmdCancel` and a combobox named `ComboBox1`.

Since `Show()` is being called modally, the code after it won't execute until the form is closed or hidden. When either button is clicked (or the form is closed by other means) then the code continues, the selected text is returned (if `OK` was clicked), and the form unloads itself.

The beauty of doing it this way is that your calling code doesn't need to worry about instantiating and destroying the form each time it's called. It's just a single statement to load the form and get the return value.

Of course, you'll need to add the code to populate the combobox with whatever items you wish to display.